# PowerShell - Replacing all occurrences, except one, of a certain character in a string

Tags: powershell, regex

Writing a PS form in SAPIEN PS studio 2018.

Problem: I have a random string, in text box, that contains square brackets in it ('[' or ']')

Expected: Need to allow the user to type only one brackets sequence

For example:

```
1> bla[]bla //valid
2> []bla //valid
3> bla[[] // not valid
4> b[la[] // not valid
5> b]la[] // not valid
etc..
```

My code so far(Used the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089631/replacing-only-the-first-occurrence-of-a-word-in-a-string)):

```
if ($this.Text -match '(\[){2,}') { $this.Text = $this.Text -replace '(.*?)\[(.*)', '$1$2' }
if ($this.Text -match '(\]){2,}') { $this.Text = $this.Text -replace '(.*?)\](.*)', '$1$2' }
```

This code works only when the brackets are matched together(example 3), but it doesn't work for example 4 and 5, any suggestions please?

**ANSWER, by Lieven Keersmaekers**

```
@('bla[]bla','[]bla','bla[[]','b[la[]','b]la[]') | % { $_ -replace '\[.*\]', '[]' -replace '\](?=.*\[)'}
```

Comment: Why not just check for the existence of an opening bracket and if that is the case for [<whatever>]? Your example text doesn't make a lot of sense so it's hard to tell whenever there might not be a better example.

Comment: You mean by stack?

Comment: Essentially you're interested in whenever you have proper bracket (nesting). As you only want to allow a single bracket pair (as I understand it) just use strpos([) > strpos(]) and as all you do is just remove the bracket just use a simple replace to replace those brackets with nothing.

Comment: How do you know *which* bracket to remove in your fourth example?

Comment: Should remove "la[" string, nothing should be inside the brackets

Comment: and you don't want to have nested brackets?

Comment: This works for the examples you've given `@('bla[]bla','[]bla','bla[[]','b[la[]','b]la[]') | % { $_ -replace '\[.*\]', '[]' -replace '\](?=.*\[)'}`

Comment: Thx @LievenKeersmaekers, works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works for the examples and constraints you've given

```
-replace '\[.*\]', '[]' -replace '\](?=.*\[)'
```

The gist of this is to

- `'\[.*\]', '[]'` removes everything between the first open and last closing bracket
- `'\](?=.*\[)'`removes remaining closing brackets having a positive lookahead for an opening bracket

Example

```
@('bla[]bla','[]bla','bla[[]','b[la[]','b]la[]') | % { 
    $_ -replace '\[.*\]', '[]' -replace '\](?=.*\[)'}
```

Returns

```
bla[]bla
[]bla
bla[]
b[]
bla[]
```